# Ruby: how to find a date by the year day

Tags: ruby, activesupport

How is it possible to find the date based on the current year's day?
For example, you have the year's day 235, which date does it corresponds to?

For example, you can find a year's day as follows:

```rb
Date.today.yday
#=> 126 (for May 6, 2021)
```

How to achieve the opposite?

```
Date.some_method(126)
#=> 2021-05-06
```

I tried as follows:

```rb
now = Date.today
#=> Thu, 06 May 2021
start_year = now.beginning_of_year
#=> Fri, 01 Jan 2021 

start.advance(days: (start.yday + 126))
#=> Sat, 08 May 2021
```

Why there is a difference of 2 days?

Comment: The difference comes from the fact that `start.yday` is 1, not zero. So to get the first day of the year you must advance by 0 days (you're already there) and so it should be `.advance(days: 125)` to get 126th day of the year (while you're advancing by 127)

Comment: Ah, thank you, nice catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.ordinal` gives you the date, given the year and the number. You can even specify a negative number, which would calculate the date counting backwards from the end of the year. [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-ordinal)

Comment: I feel like i Should now delete my answer :) Is there a way of transferring upvotes?

Comment: Thank you, @steenslag, I didn't know it exists :). Really useful: `Date.ordinal(2021, 126) #=> #<Date: 2021-05-06 ((2459341j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`

Answer (score 4):

This should work (pure ruby):

```
def day_of_year(num)
  Date.new(Date.today.year) + num - 1
end

day_of_year(1) #=> 01/01/2021
day_of_year(235) #=> 23/08/2021
```

Another option:

```
def day_of_year(num)
  Date.strptime(num.to_s, "%j")
end

day_of_year(1) #=> 01/01/2021
day_of_year(235) #=> 23/08/2021
```

Note: @steenslag posted the actually correct answer - please go and upvote.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you add parens, then the integer day offset is calculated first and only then the date calculation is made. Whereas this version does date calculations twice.

Just FYI, it will not make much difference in real-life-code but does not make your code more complicated either. 

`Date.new(Date.today.year) + (num - 1)`

Comment: @Pascal - I guess it could be some difference in lower level languages. There are no primitive types in ruby so there is very little difference between date and integer calculation. Just for fun I have benchmark both options - there is absolutely no difference in the average of 10^12 runs.

Comment: @BroiSatse

I actually did a Benchmark before writing the comment just to be sure the difference is noticeable.

https://gist.github.com/pascalbetz/efe2c12861d1f3c167a6c00a1ca1f81a

Care to share yours? Curios as to why you did not notice any difference. Perhaps a different ruby version?

In any case: it is cheaper to add integers (primitve or object) than to create a new Date object.

Comment: Ah, great - your benchmark is better (and I've learnt about ips, that's cool). :) However, we are still talking about a difference of 10^-7 of a second. If I were to work on the project where this would make the slightest difference then ruby is not the language to go with :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Date.today - (Date.today.yday - 126)